# How does CMake specify "Platform Toolset" for a Visual Studio 2015 project?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

There is a VS2015 project which is generated by CMake and I want to change its "Platform Toolset".

[image: "Platform Toolset" Location]

I have tried these solutions but it doesn't work:

1. `set (CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET "v120")`
2. `cmake -T "v120"`

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First of all: remove the CMakeCache.txt if you have already generated your project. Next run cmake:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14" -T v120
```

Whenever you need to change your generator(and the toolset is a part of it) you should remove the CMakeCache.txt file.

Comment: @P.X, if it helped you, please, accept the answer by hitting a tick sign near the answer

Answer (score 6):

Using `CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET` is better than using the `-T` option.

It's not required to remove the CMakeCache.txt file when re-generating CMake.

e.g.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16" -A Win32 -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=v140
```

Comment: Why is `CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET` better than `-T`?  Do they do different things, or do you mean it is easier to read/maintain build scripts when you use the full name?

Answer (score 2):

you can also assign platform toolset per-project using example below:

```
set_target_properties( MyProjectName 
          PROPERTIES
               VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET ClangCL )
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone finding this, the solution is to use CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION.

eg.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=8.1 .
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` is used to set the CMake *host system version* (i.e. the OS version), **not** the *target platform toolset* version.

Comment: You appear to be confusing CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION  with CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION.html

"The version of the operating system for which CMake is to build"

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION.html#variable:CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION
    
"The OS version CMake is running on."