# How do I use CMake to set the VS platform toolset property?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Rather that using the method [presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35549164/5922876), I would like to manually set a property of a Visual Studio project in the CMake file, in this case, the Platform Toolset to `$(DefaultPlatformToolset)` [(see this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA0aN.png), which is a VS macro. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally what [`CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET.html) is used for, however, it should be used within a toolchain file, not within the CMakeLists.txt.

> Native build system toolset name specified by user.
>
> Some CMake generators support a toolset name to be given to the native
>   build system to choose a compiler. If the user specifies a toolset
>   name (e.g. via the cmake -T option) the value will be available in
>   this variable.
>
> The value of this variable should never be modified by project code. A
>   toolchain file specified by the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE variable may
>   initialize CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET. Once a given build tree has been
>   initialized with a particular value for this variable, changing the
>   value has undefined behavior.

I think if you set it before making your `project` call, then it will theoretically still work, although obviously this is not the supported method of using it, so compatibility may vary.

Comment: I can confirm that it works to define `CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET` before the `project` call. In my case, setting v120_xp from VS2017.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Simply doing `set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "$(DefaultPlatformToolset)")` in a toolchain file worked like a charm. Thanks!