# How to set MSVC Target Platform Version with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I'm searching for way to set *Target Platform Version* of **MSVC** project generated with [CMake](https://cmake.org/). I found the following [ticket](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15670&nbn=14) in **CMake** issue tracker which is now closed. I'm with latest `3.9.1` version of **CMake**. But the solution described there seems to not work. I tried

```
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 8.1)
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

How to set *Terget Platform Version* when using CMake?

**Afterwords:**

Now I checked that setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` from command line when generating solution works but I want if possible to be able to set this from `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=8.1 ..\source\
```

At least it will be good to be able to set this from **CMake GUI**.

Comment: Have a look at the -T command line option of CMake. (e.g. `-T v120` or `-T v141`) . See this answer for further information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549164/how-cmake-specify-platform-toolset-for-a-visual-studio-2015-project

Comment: Never mind, I mixed up Target Platform Version and Target Platform Toolset.

Comment: You can set this in GUI. You just click the button "Add Entry". Beware that a full version string, like it appears  in "Windows SDK Version" property page in VS must be entered. For me worked with: CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION = 10.0.17763.0

Comment: Must add this entry before click 'Configure'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 8.1 CACHE TYPE INTERNAL FORCE)` before first usage of `project` solves the problem.

Comment: Note that it must be before the first `project` of your *top-level* `CMakeLists.txt`, since it needs to be set globally at generation time (obvious, but I missed it).