# How to pass latest Windows SDK version to CMake?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake

How to pass latest Windows SDK version to CMake so I don't need to go in Visual Studio and put it manually from Configuration Proprieties - General?

[image: VS]

I've search on internet and I've found the CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION variable and I've tried to use

```
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0)
```

and

```
set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0 (latest installed version))
```

but I still get version 10.0.18362.0 set as default

Comment: You only have `10.0.18362.0` installed.

Comment: Did you set the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` before any `project()` calls in your CMake project (as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693321/3987854) post)?

Comment: I've tried that but I have the same result @squareskittles

Comment: I suggest that you could remove the CMakeCache.txt if you have already generated your project. Then you could try to reset.

Comment: TY.Your ```CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION``` solved my problem. Altogether,```set (CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0.19041.0)
project(test  LANGUAGES CXX)
message(STATUS "test: ${CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION}")```